# Passing arguments down in Tkinter to a method

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

I'm struggling to get my method working correctly. I've thought about using a `lambda` function which I did for another problem and that worked, however here it does not seem to work. I'm trying to change the functions to methods and for some reason, my method is not working correctly since it has no reference to the tree. I've tried using a `lambda` function although that does not work.

My error:

```
NameError: name 'tree' is not defined
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/bitvivaz/Documents/Software Development/Python/PasswordManager/mainFrame.py", line 54, in select
    print([tree.item(x) for x in tree.selection()])
NameError: name 'tree' is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from encryption import encrypted_password, decrypt_password
import backend as db


def get_credentials(tree):
    '''Retrieves all credentials from the database and inserts it into the tree widget'''
    for row in db.show_credentials():
        tree.insert("", 'end', text=row['name'], values=(
            row['username'], decrypt_password(row['password'])))


class MainframeApp:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        # build ui
        frame_main = ttk.Frame(master)
        frame_main.config(height='600', width='600')
        frame_main.grid()

        # Creates tree widget
        tree = ttk.Treeview(frame_main)

        tree["columns"] = ("one", "two")

        tree.column("#0")
        tree.column("one")
        tree.column("two")

        tree.heading("#0", text="Website")
        tree.heading("one", text="Username")
        tree.heading("two", text="Password")

        tree.grid(padx='5', pady='5', rowspan='20')

        get_credentials(tree)

        tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", self.select, "+")

        button_add = ttk.Button(frame_main)
        button_add.config(text='Add')
        button_add.grid(column='1', padx='5', row='0')
        button_delete = ttk.Button(frame_main)
        button_delete.config(text='Delete')
        button_delete.grid(column='1', padx='5', row='1')
        button_logout = ttk.Button(frame_main)
        button_logout.config(text='Logout')
        button_logout.grid(column='1', padx='5', row='2')

        # Main widget
        self.mainwindow = frame_main

    def select(self, e):
        print([tree.item(x) for x in tree.selection()])

    def run(self):
        self.mainwindow.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Password Manager")
    app = MainframeApp(root)
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you make use of a `class` structure, certain variables are available across methods (class or instance variables), others are not (local variables).

In your case, you need to define variables you need across methods as instance variables, that is, rather than:

```
tree = ttk.Treeview(frame_main)
```

You declare:

```
self.tree = ttk.Treeview(frame_main)
```

Then you can reference the variable across methods as `self.tree`.